# Does blowing out candles count as destroying objects?

Tags: diablo-iii

I seem to have notice that hitting candles and blowing them out count as destroying an object for the "destruction" bonus. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I can confirm that you are right.